# generate an array from an array with conditions

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose i have an array

```
$x = (31,12,13,25,18,10);
```

I want to reduce this array in such a way that the value of each array element is `32`.
so after work my array will become

```
$newx = (32,32,32,13);
```

I have to generate this array in such a way the sum of array values is never greater than `32`. so to create first value, I will reduce `1` from second index value i.e. `12`, so the second value will become `11` and first index value will become `31+1 = 32`. This process should continue so that each array value becomes equal to `32`.

Comment: please explain more since I can't tell what you are asking -- show how you found the example

Comment: Dear @ZoltanToth , may be you can help me in fixing this issue, i have already told you what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to use some basic math:

```
$input = array(31,12,13,25,18,10);
$val = 32;                                // set the value: 32
$sum = array_sum($input);                 // calculate sum: 109
$output = array_fill(0, $sum/$val, $val); // fill in int(109/32) = 3 reps of 32
$rest = $sum % $val;                      // however, 109*32 = 96,
if ($rest) {                              // so if there is a rest (here 13)
    $output[] = $rest;                    // we add the remaining 13
}
```

Final `$output`:

```
array (
  0 => 32,
  1 => 32,
  2 => 32,
  3 => 13,
)
```

Comment: Oh that is so much more elegant than what I was going to put! +1

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more verbose method explaining each step taken -

```
$x = array(31,12,13,25,18,10);
$total = 0;

// get the total values of the array
foreach($x as $val){
  $total += $val;
}

// calculate whole divisions
$divisions = floor($total / 32);

// calculate remainder
$remainder = $total % 32;

$finalArr = array();

// populate array with whole whole divisions
for ($i=0;$i<$divisions;$i++){
  $finalArr[] = 32;  
}

// last element is the remainder
if($remainder > 0 ){
  $finalArr[] = $remainder;
}
```

---

Output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32
    [1] => 32
    [2] => 32
    [3] => 13
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lix , both the solutions worked.